# hello cannot locate the core snap: No such file or directory

Tags: snap

The installation of snaps goes perfectly well, but whenever I try to run a snap after the installation nothing happens (e.g. Notes won't start from the dash). Also non-GUI snaps like `hello` don't work:

```
$ hello
cannot locate the core snap: No such file or directory
```

How could I fix this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have the hello snap, notes and core installed on my computer and all of them work fine.

```
$ snap list
Name              Version           Rev  Developer         Notes
core              16.04.1           714  canonical         -
hello             2.10              20   canonical         -
notes             0.9.0~gitb6e3b34  4    notes-developers  -
```

When the hello snap is installed, the core snap is installed along with it if core is not already installed. Try updating the core snap:

```
sudo snap refresh core
```

If core is already installed the following message will be shown:

```
snap "core" has no updates available
```

Your results of running `sudo snap refresh core` were as follows:

```
sudo snap refresh core error: cannot refresh "core": cannot find snap "core"
```

So uninstall the core snap and then reinstall it.

```
sudo snap remove core hello  
sudo snap install hello # core will also be installed automatically
```

Hello is a terminal app that runs like this.

```
$ hello
Hello, world!
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but now I'm getting the following error:

`
$ sudo snap install core
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Mount snap "core" (714) (cannot install core snap "core" when core snap "ubuntu-core" is already present)
`

Refreshing doesn't work:

`
$ sudo snap refresh core
error: cannot refresh "core": cannot find snap "core"
`

And hello still doesn't work ;(

`
$ hello
cannot locate the core snap: No such file or directory
`

Comment: Whoops, the layout in the comment above is pretty messed up, I'm a bit new to askubuntu so I don't know how to fix this. But anyway, everything between the " characters is terminal output.

Comment: I removed the ubuntu-core snap because of that snap, core could not be installed. Then I installed core as you suggested and now everything works fine! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I did:

> sudo snap install core

And that did the trick. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: I didn't have "core" installed, only "core18". So the manual installation helped me as well.

Comment: I tried uninstalling purging snap-store and snapd as well with apt and snap command. At the end of the snap-store installtion I still have : *Run configure hook of "snap-store" snap if present (run hook "configure": cannot locate base snap core20: No such file or directory)*

Answer (score 1):

This indicates that you don't have the `core` snap installed (or broken). You can first check if its installed by

```
snap list
```

If it already exists, you can **refresh** the snap.

```
snap refresh core
```

If you face an error like

```
snap "core" has no updates available
```

You can `remove` and again `install` it. Or, you can do a little trick

```
snap refresh core --edge
```

And then, when the problem is fixed, switch it back to stable branch

```
snap refresh core --stable
```