# wordpres-desktop cannot locate the core snap: No such file or directory

Tags: snap

The same or similar issue seems to be on topic:

[hello cannot locate the core snap: No such file or directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/873243/hello-cannot-locate-the-core-snap-no-such-file-or-directory)

However, there is no helpful answer there.

I have the same problem and I can't find the answer anywhere.
I installed wordpress-desktop but it won't run. In terminal I get:

```
cannot locate the core snap: No such file or directory
```

When I use command: `sudo snap refresh core`
I get: `snap "core" has no updates available`
After: `snap list`

```
core               16-2     1689  canonical      -
wordpress-desktop  2.4.0    2     flexiondotorg  -
```

After: `snap --version`

```
snap     unknown
snapd    unknown
series   16
manjaro  unknown
kernel   4.11.0-1-MANJARO
```

Any idea what next? This bug seems to be widely spread but with no apparent fix or at least I didn't find any.

Comment: I just installed manajaro from scratch and installed snapd, then did snap install wordpress-desktop and it worked. Can you perhaps stop and start snapd, or reboot and try again to see if it works?

Comment: I installed wordpress-desktop on another manjaro computer. During install I got: 2017-05-19T14:29:29+02:00 INFO cannot auto connect core:core-support-plug to core:core-support: (slot auto-connection), existing connection state "core:core-support-plug core:core-support" in the way

Comment: I stopped and started again snapd.socket and snapd.refresh.timer but didn't help. It's no coincidence that the same issue is on the same system although on different computers. However, the fact that another person has a success on the same system, points that I'm doing something wrong :(.