# How do I solve this error on Ubuntu Hirsute Hippo (21.04)? Updating Core 18 " Snap has no update available"

Tags: software-center, snap, 21.04

How do I solve this error on Ubuntu Hirsute Hippo (21.04)?

```
Unable to update "Core 18": snap has no updates available"
```

[image: Screenshot of Error Updating Core 18]

It's already installed as I check with the terminal:

```
    sudo snap install core18
    
    snap "core18" is already installed, see 'snap help refresh'
```

I also try snap refresh

```
    sudo snap refresh
    All snaps up to date.
```

and I try with **Ubuntu Software** again and can't update it.

and I can't remove it as I use it by chromium and Libre Office

```
    sudo snap remove core18

    error: cannot remove "core18": snap "core18" is not removable: snap is being
           used by snaps chromium, gnome-3-28-1804, gnome-3-34-1804,
           gtk-common-themes, libreoffice and 1 more.
```

when I try to refresh it on the terminal, no update.

```
sudo snap refresh core18
snap "core18" has no updates available
```

I belive this maybe a bug with **Ubuntu Software**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [hello cannot locate the core snap: No such file or directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/873243/hello-cannot-locate-the-core-snap-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0):

It seems 20.04 was hit with this as well. Maybe the bug filtered itself into 21.04 as well?

See here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1286711/1229506

Comment: Yes, it's installed, I check the link, but not solved, still showing up and I try the terminal and find it's installed already, but not able to update it.

Comment: Try sudo snap resfresh core18. Also, snaps are a tad funny. Some people get the new updates earlier than others when they are first released. A "progressive" release so to speak. Since 21.04 "hit the market" only a short time ago, this may also be the issue.

In either case, Core18 will stay there if needed by snaps built on 18. If you have no snap currently using core18, it's safe to uninstall it.

Comment: I can't remove it, I use it with chrome.
```
sudo snap remove core18
error: cannot remove "core18": snap "core18" is not removable: snap is being
       used by snaps chromium, gnome-3-28-1804, gnome-3-34-1804,
       gtk-common-themes, libreoffice and 1 more.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to purge Snapd completely in four steps:

1. Save the list of installed snaps by running

   ```
   snap list
   ```
2. Purge snapd

   ```
   sudo apt-get autopurge snapd
   ```
3. Reinstall Snap

   ```
   sudo apt-get install snapd
   ```
4. Reinstall snaps using list from no. 1